# no response to my code

Tags: java, event-handling, applet, mouseevent, paintcomponent

I was trying to learn applets and on executing this code, there are no compile-time errors but the problem is that i m not getting any response to my code. i used simple notepad and appletviewer to get it done. On clicking on the applet, the coordinates should be displayed but it's not happening.I have tried entering the relevant html code and executing via a browser but the response is the same. Any help will be really appreciated

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
/*
<applet code="MyMouseApplet.class"
width = "400"
height = "400"> 
</applet>*/

public class MyMouseApplet extends Applet implements MouseListener{
int x,y;
String str=" ";
public void init(){
this.addMouseListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
g.drawString(str,x,y);
}
public void update(Graphics g){
paint(g);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
int x = m.getX();
int y = m.getY();
str="x:" + x + "y:" + y;
repaint();
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m){}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m){}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m){}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `Java console` of your browser?

Comment: yes but im still not getting any response

Comment: Try putting addMouseListener in start() method instead of init()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mouseClicked` function takes `x` and `y` out of scope. Do this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
     //int x = m.getX();
     //int y = m.getY();
     x = m.getX();
     y = m.getY();
     str="x:" + x + "y:" + y;
     repaint();
}
```

This will access the fields of your class, not local variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I guess it was a rookie mistake by me